# Function of isolated scope gets called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I wrote an angular code to implement Like and remove Like functionality. For this purpose I used a directive "like-directive" which takes three functions
1. upFn : code to be executed when liked
2. downFn: code to be executed when like removed
3. upvChk: function which checks whether it is liked or not. I started this with false

For some reason I cannot use a variable with ng-if. I have to use the upvChk function. But this function is getting called more than twice. It should be called only twice because I'm using ng-if twice.

Here is the codepen link http://codepen.io/puneet27/pen/jApJww/

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope',MainCtrl])
  .directive('likeDirective',[likeDirective]);
  
  function MainCtrl($scope){
    var mcl = this;
    mcl.checkUpvoted = checkUpvoted;
    mcl.upvote = upvote;
    mcl.downvote = downvote;
    
    function checkUpvoted(){
      alert("function to check whether liked or not");
      return mcl.upvoted;
    }
    function upvote(){
      alert('like completed');
      mcl.upvoted = true;
    }
    function downvote(){
      alert('dislike completed');
      mcl.upvoted = false;
    }
  }
  function likeDirective(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        upFn:'&upFn',
        downFn:'&downFn',
        upvChk:'&upvChk'
      },
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html'
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
    <like-directive up-fn="mc.upvote()" down-fn="mc.downvote()" upv-chk="mc.checkUpvoted()"></like-directive>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    <div><span id="upvote" ng-if="!upvChk()" ng-click="upFn()">Like</span><span id="upvoted" ng-if="upvChk()" ng-click="downFn()">Liked</span></div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is likely due to the way the digest cycle works in Angular. On the first run it will check the value and so call `upvChk()`. Once the first digest run completes it runs again to see if anything changed during the first digest run so it calls `upvChk()` again. The digest cycle will keep running until no changes are detected or 10 iterations are reached whereupon it will throw an error.

Comment: Is there any way to run it only once

Comment: Probably not since it is the Angular digest cycle calling it. You could try one-time binding, but I'm not sure if that works on functions.